# How can I save images in a folder with javascript? ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

with fileupload in asp.net, how can I save an image in a folder and then call and display it? Can I use ajax, jquery or javascript with web method?

```
<asp:FileUpload CssClass="image" ID="fileUpload" runat="server" />
```

I have these methods in c #, but I need it in javascript.

```
 private void SaveFile(HttpPostedFile file)
        {
            string rut = Server.MapPath("~/temp");

            if (!Directory.Exists(rut))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(rut);
            }

            string imgff= String.Format("{0}\\{1}", rut, file.FileName);

            if (File.Exists(imgff))
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "Image()", true);
            }
            else
            {
                file.SaveAs(imgff);
            }
        }
```

With this method:

```
private void carga()
        {
            try
            {
                if (fileUpload.HasFile)
                {
                    // Se verifica que la extensión sea de un formato válido
                    string ext = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
                    ext = ext.Substring(ext.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
                    string[] formatos =
                      new string[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png" };
                    if (Array.IndexOf(formatos, ext) < 0)
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "FormatoImagen()", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GuardarArchivo(fileUpload.PostedFile);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Javascript is client side are you trying to save this to the computer of the person using the web browser? If so, don't do it with javascript this will not work but make a download happen instead from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the file using the Generic Handler. Using JQuery Ajax you can upload the files to the particular folder. In the submit button call the JavaScript function

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return UploadFile();" />
```

JQuery Ajax

```
function UploadFile()
{
        $.ajax({
            url: "FileUploadHandler.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            async: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
               // Process the result
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            }
        });
}
```

FileUploadHandler.ashx.cs

```
public class FileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                string extention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                string fileName = file.FileName.Replace(extention, "") + Guid.NewGuid() + extention;
                string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/FolderName/" + fileName);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information check this [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Uploading-files-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-Generic-Handler-ASHX-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

*You can implement this way,And save the file in folder*

```
 if (file != null)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string dirUrl = "~/Uploads/";

                string dirPath = Server.MapPath(dirUrl);

                if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
                }
                string fileUrl = dirUrl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileUrl));
            }
        }
```

> Now retrieve the file from folder or database

```
if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + model.id+ "/")))
                {
                    model.Image= Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + model.id + "/"))
                     .Select(fn => "~/Uploads/" + model.id + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fn));

                    for(int i = 0; i < model.Image.Count();i++)
                    {

                    }                      
                }
```

> Preview the file using ajax like this

```
if (file.type)
                            if (regeximage.test(file.name.toLowerCase())) {
                                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                                fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                                    var file = e.target;
                                    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                                      "<div id=\"divimageId\">" + "<image  id=\"imageid\"   class=\"imageThumb\" frameborder=\'0\' src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"></image>" + "</div>" +
                                      "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove file</span>" +
                                      "</span>").insertAfter("#divimageupload");
                                    $(".remove").click(function () {
                                        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                                        $("#divimageupload").val('');
                                    });
                                }

                                fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

                            }
```